# usermac and usercaps not found

Tags: command-line, scripts, users

I'm trying to run a script on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm getting an error:

```
usermac: command not found
usercaps: command not found
```

My script:

```
check_user_db(){
    info_log -m -t "user $PGUSER"

    id $PGUSER >/dev/null 2> /dev/null || {
        info_log -m -m -t "create user $PGUSER"
        useradd $PGUSER
    }

    usermac -m ${VAL_MIN}:${VAL_MAX} -c 0:0 $PGUSER > /dev/null
    usermac $PGUSER | grep level | while read STR; do info_log -m -m -t $STR; done
    usercaps -z $PGUSER > /dev/null

    if [ -z "$(su -l postgres -c "psql -t -c '\du $PGUSER'" 2>/dev/null | grep "$PGUSER ")" ];then
        info_log -m -m -t "Create db user $PGUSER"
        su -l postgres -c "psql -c 'create role $PGUSER login INHERIT CREATEDB'" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 || fail -t "error: user ($PGUSER)"
        su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"alter role $PGUSER with password '$PGPASSWD';\"" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 || fail -t "error: user ($PGUSER)"
    fi
}
```

Do you know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Where did you get this script? Is it even intended for Linux at all? There's no such command in [any Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=focal&keywords=usermac).

Comment: Hello. What OS and version are you using?

Comment: `usermac` and `usercaps` are not normal system commands. There is a good chance these are functions that should be defined somewhere else. So please answer muru's question about where you got this, because it seems like something is missing.